# Ubuntu 20.04 Upgrade failure concerning grub-efi-amd64-signed

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, grub-efi

I got this error when running the upgrade on 2021-05-02 as proposed by the system:

```
grub-efi-amd64-signed:   
  Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.31) but 2.04-1ubuntu26.11 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 23):

I used:

apt list --upgradable to get list of packages that needed to be upgraded:

```
Listing... Done
grub-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu44 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/focal-updates 1.167+2.04-1ubuntu44 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.142.11+2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
grub-efi-amd64/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu44 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
grub-efi/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
grub2-common/focal-updates 2.04-1ubuntu26.11 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.04-1ubuntu26.9]
```

And

```
sudo apt --only-upgrade install grub-common
```

Updated that package updated everything

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you very much. I will let you know how your suggestion will work out for me. Regards, Gerardo.

Comment: I got lucky and had this issue 3 hours after you posted this answer. It worked perfectly for me. Thank you.

Comment: The internet is soo fast ;)

Comment: Today (2021-05-10) I used: "sudo apt --only-upgrade install grub-common". This was successful. After that, the system did not propose me any further full Ubuntu upgrade. So far so good I guess. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I encountered the same thing and this fixed it for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: Sadly this didn't help me. I still get an `Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code `